Projective morphisms are quasi compact and quasi separated or not
I am very new to algebraic geometry. I was reading about different kinds of morphisms between schemes. I am wondering about the following question:

Is every projective morphism quasi-compact and quasi-separated?

Thank you for your help.

A morphism $f: X \to Y$ of schemes is called projective if $X$ can be embedded as a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_Y$ for some $n$. This basically means that $x$ is given as a projective variety over $Y$.
A morphism $f: X \to Y$ is quasi-compact if the preimage of every quasi-compact open subset of $Y$ is quasi-compact in $X$. For projective morphisms, this is always true because the preimage of any affine open subset in $Y$ is a quasi-compact subset in $\mathbb{P}^n_Y$ and hence in $X$.
A morphism $f: X \to Y$ is quasi-separated if the diagonal morphism $\Delta_f: X \to X \times_Y X$ is quasi-compact. For projective morphisms, $X \times_Y X$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_Y \times_Y \mathbb{P}^n_Y$, which is itself projective over $Y$. The diagonal morphism is a closed embedding in this case, hence it is quasi-compact.
Unless I've made some silly mistake (which I don't believe I did) than I believe the answer to your question would be yes.

+1, this is correct for this definition. There is another definition of a projective morphism from EGA which is slightly different but will lead to the same conclusions (see Stacks).
